# $\frac{(p-q)\Delta x}{\Delta t}<+\infty \iff \frac{(p-q)}{\Delta x} \mbox{is bounded}$

Tags: real-analysis, stochastic-processes, markov-process, stochastic-integrals, stochastic-differential-equations

Let $p,q\in \mathbb{R}$ such that $p+q=1$ and $\Delta t, \Delta x\in \mathbb{R}$

I would like to understand why exactly $\dfrac{(p-q)}{\Delta x}$ must be bounded and not $\frac{(p-q)}{\Delta t}$, as an example,
In other words, why:
$$\frac{(p-q)\Delta x}{\Delta t}<+\infty \iff \frac{(p-q)}{\Delta x} \mbox{is bounded}$$
Is there any concept or theorem in the analysis that says so? Please mention it in your explanation.
and why ?
$$\frac{(p-q)}{\Delta x} \mbox{is bounded} \implies \lim_{\Delta t,\Delta x \to 0}(p-q)=\lim_{\Delta x \to 0}\Delta x=0$$
Thanks in advance

**Addition:**

I found
$$\lim_{\Delta t, \Delta x \to 0}\frac{(p-q)}{\Delta x}=\frac{c}{D} \implies \lim_{\Delta t, \Delta x \to 0}(p-q)=\lim_{\Delta t, \Delta x \to 0} \Delta x=0$$ but still can't know why.

[image]
.
[image]

Comment: CFL (Courant Friedrichs Lewy) condition ?

Comment: I found 
$$\lim_{\Delta t, \Delta x \to 0}\frac{(p-q)}{\Delta x}=\frac{c}{D} \implies \lim_{\Delta t, \Delta x \to 0}(p-q)=\lim_{\Delta t, \Delta x \to 0} \Delta x=0$$ but still can't know why.